# Как мне объект из базы данных перевести в класс?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, firebase-database

Так я записываю объект в базу данных `Firebase Datebase`:

```
  @IgnoreExtraProperties
public class MyObject {

    public String name;
    public String description;
    public boolean someBool;
    public int someInt;

    public MyObject ()
    {

    }

    public MyObject (String name,
                    String description,
                    boolean someBool,
                    int someInt)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.someBool= someBool;
        this.someInt= someInt;
    }

    // [START post_to_map]
    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("name", name);
        result.put("description", description);
        result.put("someBool", someBool);
        result.put("someInt", someInt);

        return result;
    }
    // [END post_to_map]
}
```

То был класс объекта, теперь как записываю:

```
 private void WriteObjects (MyObject writeObject)
{
    // Write a message to the database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Root/Layers");

    String unicID = writeObject.adress;

    Map<String, Object> objectValues = writeObject.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> objectUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    objectUpdates .put(unicID, objectValues );

    myRef.updateChildren(objectUpdates );

}
```

Теперь мне нужно в List вывести все мои MyObject из базы данных.
Вот так я пытаюсь сделать:

```
private void ReadObjects()
    {
        // Write a message to the database
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Root/Layers");

 myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                myObjects.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    MyObject newObject = postSnapshot.getValue(MyObject.class);
                    String maaaaaaaaaa = newObject.name;
                    myObjects.add(newObject );
                }
}
```

При дебаге он выдает следующее:

```
dataSnapshot: "DataSnapshot { key = "Layers", value = {name = {name, description, someBool, someInt} }" // а мне нужен key = name (наверно. Может, все правильно)
postSnapshot: "DataSnapshot { key = name, value = {name, description, someBool, someInt} }" // вот тут правильный key (наверно. Может, все правильно)
```

И программа крашится на строке

```
String maaaaaaaaaa = newObject.name;
```

Как правильно записать в класс значения из Firebase Database?

Comment: `программа крашится` с какой ошибкой? NPE?

Comment: @Peter Samokhin скорее всего. Дома буду - посмотрю. Он просто не записывает из базы данных в класс. Где-то что-то я делаю неправильно, но не могу понять где, что и как правильно

Comment: @PeterSamokhin "E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мда. Сюда я скопировал для лучшей читаемости урезанный код - например, конкретно здесь в моем объекте нет переменной `LatLng`. А в моей "оригинальной" программе она у объекта есть. В общем, проблема была из-за того, что он не мог записать в класс конкретно эту переменную. А так код полностью рабочий. Всем спасибо.
Можно этот вопрос пометить тегом "как НЕ нужно задавать вопросы, или копируйте абсолютно все, что у вас есть"